# Dropzone.js: Can't click on custom preview

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Dropzone.js looks to be incredibly finicky (anybody remember SCSI Voodoo?), or the documentation just stinks: whatever the reason, I could try 100 different combinations of classes and parameters and still not get anywhere - which is basically what I've been doing for the past 6 hours. :P

I'm trying to build a custom dropzone, as I don't want the whole form to be clickable. I've been at this for two days and am really close (I think?). However, I'm also now really stuck: my custom drop zone isn't clickable.

I've put this into a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/Labn3qg4/

```
<form id="form-post-photo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
     <div class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-default dz-file-preview" id="previews">
        <div class="dz-message">
            <h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></i><br>drag images here</h2>or tap/click to select
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="caption" id="caption" class="form-control" placeholder="Caption (optional)">
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="btn-clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
</form>
```

---

```
<script>
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

Dropzone.options.formPostPhoto = {

    url: 'file-upload.php',
    paramName: 'photo',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    //uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 4,
    maxFiles: 4,
    maxFileSize: 1,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    previewsContainer: '#previews',
    clickable:'.dz-clickable',

    init: function() {

        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#btn-submit")
        var myDropzone = this;

        // remove extra images
        myDropzone.on('maxfilesexceeded', function(file) {
            this.removeFile(file);
        });

        // tell dropzone to process all queued files.
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });

        // add a remove button to each image
        this.on('addedfile', function(file,maxFileSize) {
            var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></i>');
            var _this = this;

            // Listen to the click event
            removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                _this.removeFile(file);
            // If you want to the delete the file on the server as well, you can do the AJAX request here.
            });

            // Add the button to the file preview element.
            file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
        });

        // show the submit button only when a photo has been added
        this.on('addedfile', function() {
            $('#btn-submit').removeClass('hide').show();
            $('#btn-clear').removeClass('hide').show();
        });

        this.on('sending', function(file) {
            //alert('Sending the file' +  file.name)
        });

        this.on('queuecomplete', function(file) {
            alert('All files have been uploaded!')
        });

        // Setup the observer for the button.
        var _this = this;
        $('#btn-clear').on('click', function() {
            // Using "_this" here, because "this" doesn't point to the dropzone anymore
            _this.removeAllFiles();
            _this.removeAllFiles(true);
        });
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you are missing the url option that is required as Dropzone does not know where to post without an action attribute.

Refer to the **Create dropzones programmatically** in the dropzone documentation. For e.g., I'm using the following:

```
<form>     
<div class="dropzone dz-default dz-file-preview dz-clickable" id="my-dropzone">
            <label class="message dz-message">
                <h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></i><br>drag images here</h2>or tap/click to select
            </label>
        </div>
        </form>
        <button id="submit-all">
          Submit all files
        </button> 
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/dropzone.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $("div#my-dropzone").dropzone({ url: "/planner/create" })
              Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

                    // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
                    autoProcessQueue : false,

                    init : function() {
                        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
                        myDropzone = this;
                        $("#submit-all").hide();

                        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                            myDropzone.processQueue();
                            // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
                        });

                        // You might want to show the submit button only when
                        // files are dropped here:
                        this.on("addedfile", function() {
                            $("#submit-all").show();
                            // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
                        });

                    }
                };
        </script>
```

Comment: Weird, as I do have a URL set in my options. Regardless, what you provided works. Thanks!